# regular expression with limited special characters in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, validation

I would like to all alphanumeric data + 
only these following 4 special character are allowed.

```
' (single quote)
- (hyphen)
. (dot)
 single space
```

I tried this :

```
var userinput = $(this).val();
var pattern = [A-Za-z0-9_~\-!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)]+$

if(!pattern.test(userinput))
{
  alert('not a valid');
}​
```

but it is not working.

Comment: In what way is it not working? I expect an answer in the range of "it matches input X when it shouldn't" to "my computer tries to kill me when i run it".

Comment: The syntax for your regular expression object (`pattern`) is wrong, as is the pattern itself - if you only want four special characters why do you have a ton of extra ones included in there?

Comment: Your regex explicitely allows `_`, `~`, `!`, `@`, `#`, `$,` `%`, `^`, `&`, `*`, `(` and `)` yet according to the question I understand that they should not match... Did you just copy-paste that regex from somewhere? Or is your question missing some details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to enclose the string in `/` to have it interpreted as a regex:

```
var pattern = /[A-Za-z0-9_~\-!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)]+$/;
```

Then, you have to remove some unallowed characters (that regex is matching more than you specified):

```
var pattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9 '.-]+$/;
```

The second one is what you need. Complete code:

```
var userinput = $(this).val();
var pattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9 '.-]+$/;

if(!pattern.test(userinput))
{
  alert('not a valid');
}​
```

Besides, check what `this` points to.

Comment: You need to escape that `.`

Comment: @RGraham `.` doesn't need to be escaped in a character class. `/[.]/.test('some string') // false`

Comment: @Vache Is that a JS-only thing, or does that apply to any Regex implementation?

Comment: @RGraham it applies to any implementation: since a `[]` range can contain only literals, escaping is redundant (every symbol is  interpreted as a literal).

Answer (score 0):

"Not working" is not a helpful description of your problem.

I'd suggest this regular expresion:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\'\-\. ]+$
```